# Java fomating to get last count

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop

My main objective is to make Java read a string and from it, express how many times this one character occurs. I am having issues formating this piece of code so that the output would be like this:

```
Entered word: papaya
Letter A: 3
```

Right now what I get is this:

```
Entered word: papaya
Letter A: 1
Letter A: 2
Letter A: 3
```

This is my code. It uses scanner to ask for input from the user.

```
int aCount = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String string = scan.nextLine();

string = string.toLowerCase();

System.out.println("Entered word: " +string);

for (int i=0; i < string.length();i++)
{
    if(string.charAt(i)== 'a')
    {
        aCount++;
        if(aCount > 0)
            System.out.println("Letter A: " + aCount);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this,

```
for (int i=0; i < string.length();i++)
  {
     if(string.charAt(i)== 'a')
     {
        aCount++;
     }
  }
if(aCount > 0)
           System.out.println("Letter A: " + aCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
if(aCount > 0)
System.out.println("Letter A: " + aCount);
```

outside of your `foor` loop. It will print only one time i.e; with the last value of `aCount`.